# How to upgrade C# compiler version in Ranorex?

Tags: c#, version, ranorex

I installed the latest Visual Studio build tools but when I go into `Tools -> Project Upgrade` in Ranorex, the highest C# version I can use is 5.0, and I need at least the C# 6.0 version.

I use Ranorex 9.2.

Comment: _In order to use C# 7 in your Ranorex project, please download and install [Microsoft Build Tools 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15): afterwards, you should be able to select C# 7 in your project properties."_ - source: https://www.ranorex.com/forum/ranorex-9-and-c-7-t13639.html

Comment: I already did that to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried asking on their forums?

Comment: That was my first stop but I can't activate my account since I never received a confirmation email.

Comment: Surely their support can sort that out when you provide them with proof of purchase? It looks like [an expensive product](https://www.ranorex.com/prices/) so you would exoect that at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

Since the release of Ranorex 9.0 they support C# 7.0.
Normally you should see an option to upgrade your project, but in case you can't see it try to install the latest Microsoft Build tools, as @stuartd mentioned.

**Source:** https://ranorex.com/forum/how-to-update-c-version-in-ranorex-studio-t13926.html

Comment: I had already done that. The problem was that the latest MS build tools don't get installed at the expected location. Installing the 2015 build tools fixed the issue.